# How to make Home/End function as Ctrl on Linux

Tags: linux, emacs

I have a Thinkpad new x1 carbon. Lenovo replaced Caps Lock with a Home/End combination.
My question is: how to make Home or End function as Ctrl. (I use emacs so I swapped Caps Lock and Ctrl on my old laptop)

sorry for my poor English. :-(

[image]

========== Update =========

I tried xmodmap to do that but failed.

1. used xev to find the keycode:

   > keycode 110 (keysym 0xff50, Home)
   >
   > keycode 115 (keysym 0xff57, End)
2. used xmodmap to change key

   > xmodmap -e "keycode 110 = Control_L"
   >
   > xmodmap -e "keycode 115 = Control_L"
3. xmodmap -pke to see the mapping

   > keycode 110 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
   >
   > keycode 115 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L

   seems ok, but I cannot use them as ctrl at all.

Comment: This question is better asked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/. Anyway, Have you tried using `xmodmap` for that?

Comment: hi @Abrixas2 I tried it but failed. I attached my attempt to my post.

Comment: @crackcell: I'd use *xkbcomp* to first dump your current setup to a text file using something like *xkbcomp $DISPLAY /tmp/baselayout.xkb* and I'd then change that *.xkb* file so that home / end do send the CTRL code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use *xkbcomp* to do that.

First dump your current layout to a file (you may find the find somewhere but dumping the file should be fine):

```
xkbcomp $DISPLAY /tmp/baselayout.txt
```

*(note that before doing that, if I were you I'd make to sure to restart X / Linux in case you already messed with xmodmap, because otherwise I think you may be dumping your layout in a "weird" state)*

Then open that *baselayout.txt* (you can give it another name of course) and look for the line corresponding to LCTL:

```
   key <LCTL> {         [       Control_L ] };
```

Then change the line corresponding to your END key from this:

```
   key  <END> {         [             End ] };
```

To this:

```
   key  <END> {         [        Control_L ] };
```

Then look for the line(s):

```
   modifier_map Control { <LCTL> };
```

And add a line:

```
   modifier_map Control { <END> };
```

Now load back your modified layout file:

```
xkbcomp /tmp/baselayout.txt $DISPLAY
```

You can then use *"xmodmap -pm"* to check your modifiers.  For example on my setup, but with your "END becomes CTRL" modification (btw funny location for home/end that your laptop has):

```
$ xmodmap -pm
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock      
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_L (0x42),  Control_R (0x69),  Control_L (0x73)
...
```

Notice how 0x73 (decimal 115) / *Control_L* is a *control*. It's the code *xev* gives for *END* on my system.

Note that you *must not* mess the location of the $DISPLAY variable and you *must not* forget it. Otherwise bad things will happen (like silent failure).

Also note that I get the warnings you mention: but using *xkbcomp* (and *xmodmap* just to print the modifiers, not to configure anything) as I described above I get END to act as a control key.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply. But I still cannt do it. After running the 2nd command, it said: Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
                  Using new definition
Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
                  Using new definition
Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
                  Using new definition

Comment: Is there some way to get debug info?

Comment: @crackcell: my bad... You also need to add a line saying: *" modifier_map Control { <END> };"*  near the other *modifier_map Control ...* lines.  I'll edit my question.  By the way I get the warnings too: no issue for me.